# R timevis chart customization for Power BI

Tags: r, powerbi

I created a chart using timevis package which should show comparison of actual and planned timeline for projects completed by different teams. I'm developing this visual in R and want to import it as custom visual for Power BI.
Now I'm stuck with its looks. I don't know anything besides R to customize its looks. I wish I could add vertical scrolling. Is is even possible to do solely in R? Or can I at least adjust Team/Project column width?

I have a long list of teams and projects in real life. I blacked out the text that's there but as you can see it takes up more space than necessary. I attached [a snippet of how it looks with real life data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EERDt.png)

```
## Here is the code with sample data:
timevis( 
data = data.frame( 
start = c("2023-04-09", "2023-04-09", "2023-04-16", "2023-04-30", "2023-04-16", "2023-05-21", "2023-04-30", "2023-04-16"), 
content = rep(c("Actual", "Planned"), 4), 
group = c(4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7) 
), 
groups = data.frame( 
id = 1:7, 
content = c("Team 1", "Team 2", "Team 3","Project A", "Project B", "Project C", "Project D"),
nestedGroups = I(list(4, c(5,6), 7, NA, NA, NA, NA)) 
) 
)
```

I tried to find any resource that could possibly help me and so far [this](https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/docs/timeline/#Configuration_Options) seems like the best option however this is not in R and I'm not sure how it works. Is this the only way to go?

One thing I tried in R directly is adding verticalScroll as option and of course it didn't help at all:

```
options = list(verticalScroll = TRUE)
```

[I would like to achieve anything similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBiQb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made it work. I had to set also height so verticalScroll can actually get a chance to work. (*major facepalm*)

```
options = list(verticalScroll = TRUE),
height = 400
```